# Apache CXF/MTOM corrupts the file when run through Weblogic 12c

Tags: apache, weblogic, cxf, corruption, mtom

I am running a CXF based web service client (consumes a web service from the .net side). Things work perfectly other than the pdf file transfer.

If I run the same config via junit (spring loaded context and cxf) or I consume the same web service via soap-ui, the pdf file transfers correctly.

Once I run it through Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) the binary content of the pdf gets corrupted. Here's the example:

```
* Good File (transferred via CXF standalone / junit) * 
%PDF-1.3 
1 0 obj 
[/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] 
endobj 
9 0 obj 
<< /Length 1659 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream 
xœXÛnÛ8}_ 

* Bad File (transferred via WLS/CXF) * 
%PDF-1.3 
1 0 obj 
[/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] 
endobj 
9 0 obj 
<< /Length 1659 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream 
xœ�XÛnÛ8}_
```

You can see the stream section getting an extra byte there (this is just the beginning of the file... extra byte shows many times afterwards). Running this one windows or linux will end in corrupted transfer. Java 8. CXF 2.7 and 3.1.

I am still investigating into the problem but any ideas off the top of your heads would be appreciated.

- Is it the encoding that needs to be set/unset somewhere?
- Is it some preferred libraries on the web module that should be used?
- Is maybe just the app server patch missing? -

...

Comment: Is the version of WLS/CXF and CXF standalone / junit the same?

Comment: Yes. Last tested CXF 3.1.0.

Comment: It turns out that one of the (custom) incoming message interceptors have been encoding the whole message into UTF-8. Including the binary content of the mtom attachment. This interceptor has been acting as an incoming message logger as:

**Client.clientProxy(port).getInInteceptors().add(inLogger);**

That has worked completely fine until we started receiving saaj messages. It was easy enough to re-code the in-logging handler fixed.

However, the mystery still remains as to why this had no effect on the message when it was being received outside of the Weblogic container. No clue on that one.

Comment: Also one easy workaround to keep the original message around was to add another (starting) message interceptor by adding a message observer to the endpoint. Usual starting observer (that calls the pipeline) is the actual ClientImpl. So endpoint.addObserver(myObserver) can keep the original message around until the pipeline has finished. Save the message then call the client.

Comment: Buhh... I've spent two days on this. The problem was, that I had a logging handler attached to the port. My investigations were even worse... it was working on one Weblogic, but was not on another(same version). It was also working frm unit tests. 
Can you put your findings into the answer so that I can award you a bounty?

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. At one point I thought that weblogic's own net libraries were acting up so I ran the WLS instance with **-DUseSunHttpHandler=true** but that was no help. Thanks for the bounty. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

As I've explained in the comments, the culprit for the corruption was a custom logging handler, injected as an incoming message interceptor. It was encoding the whole message in UTF-8, including the binary content.

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getInInteceptors().add(inLogger);
```

I have however not found why this logger didn't cause issues outside of the weblogic container. Speaking to Oracle support didn't help much as they wanted me to submit a runnable test case that replicates the problem... which borders on impossible (i.e. web service is hosted by another company).

I also wanted to mention a way to easily handle the message before the message pipeline kicks off. All is needed is a custom message observer injected into the endpoint. Like this:

```
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
conduit.setMessageObserver(new MyMessageObserver(client));
```

Remember that when dealing with message content the input stream always has to be reset (one way of another) after being consumed. In your message observer you might want to save the message content then pass it on and reset it maybe on the way back. Along those lines:

```
@Override public void onMessage(Message message) {
    InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
    InputStream mis = save(is);
    is.reset();
    client.onMessage(message);
    message.setContent(InputStream.class, mis);
}
```

Other obvious message handler injections are done via In/OutInterceptors() and if you look at the pipeline you can inject them anywhere as per defined message processing phases.. ON-RECEIVE, PRE-STREAM, etc... as per http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html . These will be part of the pipeline but after the client kicks in. MyMessageObserver is before the pipeline.

Hope this helps with Apache CXF debugging...